# Probability density during equilibration

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, non-equilibrium

An ensemble of states $x$ are initially drawn from a non-equilibrium probability density $P_0(x)$.

Over time they will evolve towards the equilibrium distribution $P_\mathrm{eq}(x)$.

What I want to know is, at least approximately, the probability distribution as a function of time $t$, i.e. $P(x,t)$.

Intuitively, I would expect the decay from $P_0$ to $P_\mathrm{eq}$ to be well-described as exponential

$$ P(x,t) = \exp(-t/\tau)P_0(x) + [1-\exp(-t/\tau)]P_{\mathrm{eq}}(x) $$

This would be consistent with my experience with autocorrelation and diffusion equations.

But is it generally correct? And is there a theoretical basis for it? I'm particularly in search of something citable that addresses this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, (equilibrium) thermodynamics does not tell us anything about the dynamical behavior of the system.
One could say that this question is "outside the scope" of the framework of thermodynamics.
So while it is quite universally true that any system will approach an equilibrium state when it is in contact with a thermal reservoir, the way that the equilibrium state is approached is non-universal: it depends on the concrete system we are talking about.

In your question, you do not mention any concrete system, or what "x" actually is.
I am going to show you one example of a system, where your expectation is wrong, and another example, where your expectation is correct.

1. Consider the overdamped diffusion of a particle in a 1D Harmonic potential
   $$ V(x) = kx^2 . $$
   The equation of motion for its probability density $p_t(x)$ at time $t$ is then given by the Smoluchowski equation
   $$ \partial_t p_t(x) = \frac{1}{m\gamma} \left( \partial_x kx + k_BT \partial_x^2 \right) p_t(x) , $$
   where $m$ is the particle mass, $\gamma$ the friction constant, $k_B$ Boltzmann's constant and $T$ the temperature.
   (See for example [H. Risken, The Fokker-Planck Equation, Springer 1996].)
   Let us assume that the probability distribution is initially not centered, e.g.
   $$ p_0(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt \pi} \mathrm e^{-(x-10)^2} . $$
   We don't even need to solve the equations of motion to see that the correct solution is obviously *not* $p_t = \mathrm e^{-t/\tau} p_0 + (1 - \mathrm e^{-t/\tau}) p_{\text{eq}}$.
   As that would mean that the particles "teleport" from their initial position around $x=10$ to their final position around $x=0$.
   The correct solution will instead have the particles diffuse slowly from the initial to the final position, which means that *in an intermediate position, the probability density will first go up and then down again*.
2. Consider the thermalization of a qubit with Hamiltonian
   $$ H = \frac{\hbar\omega}{2} \sigma_z $$
   (where $\sigma_z$ is the Pauli matrix).
   The state of the qubit is given by a density matrix $\rho$. (I am taking the freedom here to let your index "x" describe a discrete set of state variables.)
   Under a standard weak coupling master equation, the components
   $$ \rho(t) = \frac 1 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 + p_z(t) & p_x(t) - \mathrm i p_y(t) \\ p_x(t) + \mathrm i p_y(t) & 1 - p_z(t) \end{pmatrix} $$
   have the following time evolution (assuming $\omega$ is small):
   \begin{align}
   p_x(t) &= \mathrm e^{-\Gamma_2 t} p_x(0) \\
   p_y(t) &= \mathrm e^{-\Gamma_2 t} p_y(0) \\
   p_z(t) &= \mathrm e^{-\Gamma_1 t} p_z(0) + (1 - \mathrm e^{-\Gamma_1 t}) p_{z,\text{eq}}
   \end{align}
   where $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are some rates.
   (Details: [H.-P. Breuer and F. Petruccione, The Theory of Open Quantum Systems, Oxford University Press 2002].)

Answer (score 0):

https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2248 (J. Stat. Mech. P07029 (2009)): "Using the recently derived Dissipation Theorem and a corollary of the Transient Fluctuation Theorem (TFT), namely the Second Law Inequality, we derive the unique time independent, equilibrium phase space distribution function for an ergodic Hamiltonian system in contact with a remote heat bath. We prove under very general conditions that any deviation from this equilibrium distribution breaks the time independence of the distribution. Provided temporal correlations decay, and the system is ergodic, we show that any nonequilibrium distribution that is an even function of the momenta, eventually relaxes (not necessarily monotonically) to the equilibrium distribution."